# Can a dynamic programming problem be transformed into a linear algebra problem?

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization

Here is a simple standard economic problem:

> Let Robin Crusoe have an endowment $w_0$ of *lembas* bread. She is immortal and discounts at a rate of $\beta$ per period. Each period (from $t=0$ on) she choose to consume some amount $c_t\in [0,w_t]$, and since *lembas* bread does not decay, $w_{t+1} = w_t - c_t$. Optimize Robin's utility $$\sum_{t=0}^\infty \beta^t u(c_t)$$
>   subject to the constraint $w_{t+1} + c_t = w_t$.

Here $u$ is a concave function, e.g., $u(c) = c^{\theta}$ or $u(c) = \log(c)$.

To solve this using dynamic programming, one uses Bellman's principle that each period, a choice will be made given optimal behavior in all future periods. Thus one obtains a series of value functions $v_t$ solving
$$v_t(w_t) = \max_{w'\in [0,w_t]} u(w'-w_t) + \beta v_t(w').$$
This is to say, on the constraint set $\Omega_t = [0,w_t]$, $v_t$ is a stationary point of the maximization operator $$T_uv(b) = \max_{b'\in \Omega_t}u(b'-b) + \beta v(b'),$$
acting on (say) $L^\infty(\Omega_t)$.

This is not a linear operator, so tools from linear algebra cannot be brought to bear. I'm wondering if the problem can be "linearized" in the following sense:

> Is there a *linear* operator $L_u$ acting on $L^\infty(\Omega_t)$ which "contains the same information as $T_u$" in the sense that a stable point of $T_u$ will either be an eigenvector of $L_u$ or will lie in the kernel of $L_u$?

I've played around with the idea that an integral operator $L$, say, $Lv(b) = \int U(b,b')v(b')db'$, might be able to capture this maximization problem, but I'm afraid I just don't yet have the intuition to see how this should play out. So I put the question to you.

Comment: Have you considered offering a bounty to get the attention to this question? I would like to chip in too. Thanks.

Comment: in the formulation, do you mean $w_{t+1}=w_t - c_t$?

Comment: @Eupraxis1981 Yes, thank you.

Comment: Does Crusoe has only the initial endowment to consume, during her infinite life?

Comment: Are you certain you want to maximize over the state variable? Utility comes from consumption, not from endowment. Why go roundabout?

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos Yes, only the initial endowment. This is known as the "cake-eating problem". As far as the state variable, it has to enter into the problem somehow because it's what links consumption between periods. I'm not certain about this particular formulation.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. A problem I face with your question is that a rather trivial optimization problem like the "cake-eating problem" (I have almost forgotten it!) attempts to motivate a very abstract (and interesting) question. For the moment, I feel "blinded" by the easy solution using traditional lagrangean method, something that does not make it easier to think the actual question, i.e. "dynamic programming to linear algebra". We 'll see...

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos If you'd like, I can change the question to the neoclassical growth model.

Comment: What makes you suspect something like this should be true at all? Dynamics programming in this case is just Banach fixed point theorem applied to your $T_u$?, which is a contraction on a Banach space. As finite dimensional version of your conjecture would consider a contraction on, say, $\mathbb{R}^2$. Not clear why there should be a corresponding operator with the properties you describe even in that case.

Answer (score 2):

You may be interested in the policy iteration algorithm.

To clear something up the value function is not time-dependent and solves
$$
v(w)=\max_{w'\in [0,w]}\{ u(w-w')+\beta v(w')\}.
$$
This should be solved on the interval $[0,w_0]$ for $w_0$ the initial allotment of bread.

For policy iteration, fix a policy $c:[0,w_0]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $0\leq c(w)\leq w$ and then $v^c$ is solved by the linear equations
$$
v^c(w)=u(c(w))+\beta v^c(w-c(w)).
$$
This step will use linear algebra, but the next step still requires non-linear maximization.

Given $v^c$ choose the next policy by
$$
c'(w)={\rm argmax}_{d\in [0,w]}\{ u(d)+\beta v(w-d)\}.
$$

If you start with the policy $c_0(w)=w$, then $v^0(w)=u(w)$ and the first step finds
$$
c_1(w)={\rm argmax}_{d\in [0,w]}\{ u(d)+\beta u(w-d)\}.
$$

This procedure often converges very rapidly but may not be exactly what you are looking for.  Cheers!

Comment: +1 for policy iteration, this was a standard algorithm we used to solve MDPs in an undergrad stochastics course.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Neal: This may not be what you are looking for, as I don't know if I can offer the more technical answer regarding linearizations and kernels, but it occurred to me that the following condition might be a useful solution approach:

Select $c_t : u(c_t) = \beta u(w_t-c_t)\;,\; \sum\limits_{t=0}^{\infty} c_t = w_0$ That way, you eat in time t until the opportunity cost for eating the rest becomes negative relative to eating the rest it the next day.

Again, not a complete answer, but maybe that will help you make progress?

Comment: Actually, one would want $u'(c_t) = \beta u'(w_t - c_t)$ so that you eat in time $t$ until the marginal opportunity cost of the rest becomes negative relative to eating the rest of it the next day. This is the beginning of a standard sequential approach to solving these problems.

Comment: I hope that didn't come across as rude; I didn't mean it that way.

Comment: No offense taken, I think that was what I was getting at. Good luck with your problem.